# Is cartesian product of two sets a subset of power set of power set of their union?

Tags: proof-writing

Let X,Y be two sets. Is this true that "$X\times Y$ is subset of $P(P(X\cup Y)$"?

I tried to solve like this:
If we choose an element of $X\times Y$, then it should be an element of

$P(P(X\cup Y)$.

Let this element be A. Assume A is an element of $X\times Y$. It means A has 2 elements, one from the set X and one from the set Y.

So, we need to show A is an element of $P(P(X\cup Y)$. It means that A is subset of $P(X\cup Y)$. Therefore, if we choose an element of A, it should be an element of $P(X\cup Y)$.

We assumed that A has 2 elements, one from the set X and one from the set Y.  Let the element from set X be x and the element from set Y be y.

x and y are elements of $P(X\cup Y)$. Then, x and y are subset of $X\cup Y$.
So if we choose an element of x or y, it should be an element of $X\cup Y$.

I don't know the rest of solution. Because x and y do not have to be set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos They may not have used MathJax properly, but in this case, with a minimum of goodwill, the question is not really impacted. I have no problems whatsoever understanding the math they write. There are other, more important issues to focus on with this post. Such as the lack of [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You can use LaTeX/MathJax operators `\times` and `\cup` for a cross multiplication sign and for sets union.

Comment: Your question looks like a homework. If you want the community to help you, please show your own effort – what you tried and where you stuck; what your trouble with the problem is, whether some what part is incomprehensible, etc. See also [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am really sorry for bad-writing. As you guess, I am a newbie on this website. I think that it will be better with time. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Just use the _Edit_ link :) and add lacking information to your question.

Comment: Yes, let $(x,y)\to\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to write the symbol of being an element of a set, the symbol of union, and the symbol of intersection. Therefore, I tried to write the problem as short as possible.

Comment: You need to be careful and contemplate in which way (if at all) your course considers an ordered pair $(x,y)$ a set and how this set is constructed from its components $x$ and $y$. It seems that at some point you think that $(x,y)=\{x,y\}$, which is certainly not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not correct.

The mistake happens here:

> Assume $A$ is an element of $X\times Y$. It means $A$ has $2$ elements, one from the set $X$ and one from the set $Y$.

This is not true. You should check the definitions that your textbook uses, but the most standard definitions used are as follows:

- An "ordered pair" $(a,b)$ is defined as the set $\{a, \{a,b\}\}$.
- The set $X\times Y$ is defined as the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Using the definitions I wrote above, the statement you wrote is **false**.